# Definite integral solving through a contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I would like to calculate the following definite integral

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-x\,u\,i}e^{R\,e^{\,u\,i}}du$$

where $x,R>0$ in terms of elemental or special functions.

A first attempt

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-x\,u\,i}e^{R\,e^{\,u\,i}}du=-i\,\int_Cz^{-x-1}\,e^{R\,z}\,dz$$

with $C$ the unit circle.

It's correct? In this case, how continue?

Any help or any other way to solve it will be welcomed

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is correct if $x$ is an integer (and in that case you get $2\pi R^x/x!$ following, say, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) approach). Otherwise, you have a multivalued integrand, so the contour integral isn't well-defined. But one can do $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-xui}e^{Re^{ui}}du=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{R^n}{n!}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(n-x)u}~du=2\sin x\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-R)^n}{n!(n-x)}$$ where (analytic continuation of) the lower [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) appears.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left. \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
\expo{-\ic xu}\expo{R\expo{\ic u}}\dd u
\,\right\vert_{\ x, R\ >\ 0}} =
\left.\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
z^{-x}\,\expo{Rz}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic u}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ic\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
z^{-x - 1}\,\expo{Rz}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,&\,\,
\ic\int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\pars{-\xi}^{-x - 1}\,
\expo{\ic\pi\pars{-x - 1}}\,\expo{R\xi}\,\dd \xi
\\[2mm] + &\
\ic\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\bracks{\epsilon^{-x - 1}\,
\expo{\ic\pars{-x - 1}\theta}}
\bracks{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic}\dd\theta
\\[2mm] + &\
\ic\int_{-\epsilon}^{-1}\pars{-\xi}^{-x - 1}\,
\expo{-\ic\pi\pars{-x - 1}}\,\expo{R\xi}\,\dd \xi
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ic\expo{-\ic\pi x}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\xi^{-x - 1}\,
\,\expo{-R\xi}\,\dd \xi + {2\epsilon^{-x}\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}
\\[2mm] &\
\,\,\, + \ic\expo{\ic\pi x}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\xi^{-x - 1}\,
\,\expo{-R\xi}\,\dd \xi
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\sin\pars{\pi x}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\xi^{-x - 1}\,
\,\expo{-R\xi}\,\dd \xi + {2\epsilon^{-x}\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ \epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\,\,\, &\
2\expo{-R}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x} +
2R\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\xi^{-x}\expo{-R\xi}\,\dd\xi
\end{align}
The last integral *converges*, when
$\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$, whenever $\ds{\Re\pars{x} < 1}$.
In such a case,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left. \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
\expo{-\ic xu}\expo{R\expo{\ic u}}\dd u
\,\right\vert_{\substack{R\ >\ 0 \\[1.5mm] \Re\pars{x}\ <\ 1}}} \\[5mm] = &\
2\expo{-R}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x} +
2R^{x}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}
\int_{0}^{R}\xi^{-x}\expo{-\xi}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm] = &\
2\expo{-R}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x} +
2R^{x}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}\xi^{-x}\expo{-\xi}\,\dd\xi -
\int_{R}^{\infty}\xi^{-x}\expo{-\xi}\,\dd\xi}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{2\expo{-R}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x} +
2R^{x}\,{\sin\pars{\pi x} \over x}
\bracks{\Gamma\pars{-x + 1} - \Gamma\pars{-x + 1,R}}} \\ &
\end{align}
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{\cdots}\ \mbox{and}\
\Gamma\pars{\cdots,\cdots}}$ are the
[Gamma and Incomplete Gamma Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.2), respectively.